# How to obtain my cubicle in test chamber 15 of chapter 3?

Tags: portal-2

I'm in Chamber 15 in Chapter 3:

[image]

And I'm wondering how to get to the cubicle among those turrets. I know I can jump up on either side of the room, but I can't seem to spot where to built my next bridge to get up there with the turrets.

Any hints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Aerial Faith Plates are how you get up.

**Answer:**

> When you use the faith plates, you'll notice you sail clear over where you want to land—on the catwalk, high left side of the picture.  Use the light bridge to stop you from going all the way.  You can then walk over a clear catwalk (left in the picture) and drop down right on the cube.

Comment: I actually tried shooting there (on the top left) before, but it didn't seem to work. But I had a sun glare preventing me from seeing the wall properly, which probably explains why I missed it.

Comment: Side note: This is a good chamber to get the Pturretdactyl achievement.